# Node.js open in a new console without pause

Tags: node.js

I'm very newby in node.js world, and I'm doing the first steps, but I can't step forward because when I try to do any operation from node.js command prompt in Windows 10, the node.js console is opened and closed very fast and I haven't time enough to read the errors or anything that is written on console. Is there any way to configure node.js to stop the console before to quit it? Or to execute on same opened Node.js command prompt.

For example I'm unable to read the version of different modules installed, the console opens and closes very fast.

I've tried windows standard command line, node.js command prompt, an application called cmder, and in all instructions related to node it throws a new window with node.exe. If the command waits user prompt the console (node.exe) is paused, but when I try an application that only log some data (like npm --version) I can't see the result, because after log, the console is closed.

Some time ago, I've tried in Windows 7, and I remember that the node prompt was opened on the same command console. I don't know if it's the SO, or the node.js version (4.4.4 LTS).

Comment: Use Windows' CMD to run Node.js scripts.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Marc have you tried just using `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Yes Rushi, the same result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch! I've found the solution, I was trying to avoid the annoying "run as administrator" dialog and I've configured the node application properties checking the flag "Compatibility > Run This Program As An Administrator". That was the source of all my problems!

Hope it helps anyone!